# In permutation group $S_n (n \geq 5)$, if $H$ is the smallest subgroup containing all $3$-cycles, then which one of the following is true?

Tags: group-theory

In permutation group $S_n (n \geq 5)$, if $H$ is the smallest subgroup containing all $3$-cycles, then which one of the following is true?

(i) $H=S_n$, 
(ii) $H=A_n$, 
(iii) $H$ is Abelian, 
(iv) $|H|=2$

In the above problem, if $H=S_n$, then $H$ is definitely not smallest(, Although I don't have a clear inductive proof for the same). If $H=A_n$ then I think, this might be an option, but I don't have any solid evidence to conclude it. $H$ need not be Abelian, that's a conclusion we can say for sure by trying out various examples. Any hint(s) will be highly appreciated.

I found this post the closest related to this topic [Show that if $K$ is a normal subgroup of $H$ such that $H/K$ is abelian, then K contains all of the 3-cycles.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789871/show-that-if-k-is-a-normal-subgroup-of-h-such-that-h-k-is-abelian-then-k), but it's quite different as I want to prove that "In permutation group $S_n (n \geq 5)$, if $H$ is the smallest subgroup containing all $3\text{-cycles}$, $\color{green}{\text{a possible conclusion holds}}$, but this question provides two informations and then asks to prove the subgroup contains all $3\text{-cycles}$. I think there might be numerous post associated with the same topic, but unfortunately I couldn't find any...

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142541/discussion-on-question-by-franklin-in-permutation-group-s-n-n-geq-5-if-h); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

A sequence of hints, which you will hopefully be able to flesh into a full argument:

1. Every product of 3-cycles is an even permutation. Can you find an element of $S_n$ which is not a product of 3-cycles?
2. [Any group containing all 3-cycles contains the alternating group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914338/the-alternating-group-is-generated-by-three-cycles). Which subgroups of $S_n$ contain $A_n$?
3. Write down an example of two 3-cycles which don't commute.
4. We said earlier that $H$ contains $A_n$. How big is $A_n$?

Comment: How can we find such an element in $S_n$ which is not a product of $3$ cycles as no information is given about $n$ apart from $n\geq 5$ ? How can we search in $S_n$ when we don't know what $n$ is?

Comment: @Franklin Since every product of 3-cycles is an even permutation, what sort of permutations are *not* products of 3-cycles?

Comment: The odd permutations are not product of $3$ cycles. As for your second hint, I dont understand which subgroups of $S_n$ contains $A_n$? I have no idea about it...

Comment: @Franklin So if you can find an odd permutation in $S_n$, then that won't be in $H$. $A_n$ is exactly half of $S_n$ (since there are an equal number of odd and even permutations). Since $A_n \le H \le S_n$, $|A_n| \le |H| \le |S_n| = 2|A_n|$, and there are no divisors of $x$ between $x$ and $x/2$. Hence $H$ is either $A_n$ or $S_n$.